# change the textArea font with selecting items from comboBox

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, combobox, textarea

dear Java developers I've got some problem and I'm expecting yours help please help me if you can, I add a textArea and a comboBox I wanna change the font size of textArea whenever I chose the font size from comboBox the textArea should be changed automatically[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg1Ez.png)

Comment: Please post your code instead of images!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first add a listener to your comboBox. And after that simply change the font size with the value from the selection.

SWT example:

```
 yourCombo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            String currentSelection = combo.getItem(combo.getSelectionIndex());
            int fontSize = Integer.valueOf(currentSelection); 
            yourTextArea.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Segoe UI", fontSize, SWT.NORMAL));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Now i saw on your picture you are using something other than SWT. The code should be really similar anyway. As others mentioned you should put your code instead of a picture and choose your tags wisely